# Putting Change Event

Tags: jquery

When i set the value its working when will i get it based on the textbox its not working the first code is came from textbox how should i do this ? or what method should i use ? do i need change event ? where should i put ?

First Code Not Working

```
 var values = $("#imei").val();
$('#tags').val(values.split(','));
```

Second Code Working

```
var values = "865966028110134,867310021514653,867310021453217";
$('#tags').val(values.split(','));
```

Comment: Please give us some more code. Show us a jsfiddle of what you are trying to do.

Comment: When your text comes from a textbox you need a event to handle the value. `change` could be one event or `submit`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k5mvhf4n/#&togetherjs=RTaHkGfset

Comment: i need to set the selected dynamically

Comment: In your fiddle there is no `#tags` element. I don't know what you are trying to archive. Do you need the selected values of the select element seperated by `,` or do you want to add values to the select element based on input field?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, now I understand a little bit better what you are trying to do. The problem here is that you are getting the value of the #imei text input and of course at the moment of loading the page, that value is empty. What you need to do is bind everything to the change or input event, so that when you check the value of the text input it will happen everytime after you type. Look at this:

```js
var imei = $("#imei");

imei.on('input', function(){
 $('#strings').val($(this).val().split(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="imei" type="text" class="form-control" id="imei">

<select name='strings' id="strings" multiple style="width:100px;">
  <option value="865966028110134">865966028110134</option>
  <option value="867310021514653">867310021514653</option>
  <option value="867310021453217">867310021453217</option>
  <option value="123094">123094</option>

</select>
```

Comment: i did not input the value in database it will depend on what item will select in database

Comment: thats why i thought the change event will do :(

Comment: What is it exactly what you want?

Comment: i have database that hold some value once i click the button it will fill up the textbox and the value of textbox should be automatically selected in option

Comment: @Barry Meijer What is an `input` event in jQuery?

Comment: @Carlos Jhon manlulu I cannot follow you. Where is your button in jsfiddle?